# The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0,

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, sharepoint-clientobject

In the MSCRM2011 IFD environment got this error, but in on premise doesn't have this problem.

I check the GAC of CRM server and the client machine, the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" is there. I don't understand where is the application is searching for the 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'

> The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.The application terminated with an error.The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your first line. It was my understanding that an IFD environment was basically an on-premise installation but setup for access over the web.

What application is failing here? A Crm process or something custom?

In any case here are some suggestions:

1. Reset the crm web server (iisreset) - if the process is running synchronously (to make sure it picks up the latest .dlls)
2. Reset the crm asynchronous service - if the process is running asynchronously (to make sure it picks up the latest .dlls)
3. Is 14.0.0.0 the correct version? Compare with your working installation
4. Do you have your deployment spilt over multiple servers? E.g. seperate application and platform servers, in that case make sure the .dll is in the gac on all servers.